# How to get data once from firebase by ID

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, fetch

Hello im trying to get the user email of each message. (Each message (chat) have an userid). 
I get the whole user data throught getUser on the *ngIf. And then just show the email. It works and on the website there isn't any repeat of data, but the tab soon freezes unless I don't pause with debugger. I don't know why but it makes an infinite loop. 
It looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4VDq.png It makes thousands of console logs.

This is getUser:

```
  getUser(uid:string){
    this.userCollection = this.db.collection('users', ref => ref.where('uid', '==', uid));
    this.userCollection.valueChanges().subscribe(queriedItems => {
      this.userDT=new Usermodel(queriedItems[0].uid,queriedItems[0].email,queriedItems[0].displayName,queriedItems[0].photoURL,queriedItems[0].emailVerified);
    });
    console.log(this.userDT.email)
    return this.userDT;
  }
```

and I get the data in the HTML calling it directly:

```
<div class="msg_container_other" *ngIf="getUser(chat.uid); let otherUser">
                  {{chat.content}}
                  <span class="msg_time"><i class="fas fa-check-double" style="color: #292929;"></i> {{otherUser.email}}. {{ chat.date | date:'d/M/y H:mm'}}</span>
</div>
```

If you need to see what is chats: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ttfod.png and more context on html:https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6yXk.png

I've been several days trying things and don't know what else to try. 
If I remove the subscription of getUser like this:

```
  getUser(uid:string){
    this.userCollection = this.db.collection('users', ref => ref.where('uid', '==', uid));

    console.log(this.userDT.email)
    return this.userDT;
  }
```

Then it doesn't loops, but of course can't get data then.

People have told me that isn't the good way to get data once because im subscribing so I tried this way but have same effect infinite loop.

```
    getUser(uid:string){


    this.userCollection = this.db.collection('users', ref => ref.where('uid', '==', uid));
    this.userCollection.get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data().email);
            return doc.data().email;
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
}
```

This getUser doesn't works either it also makes infinite loop :/ cant believe i cant find how to get a single data by query

```
     return this.db.collection('users', ref => ref.where('uid', '==', uid)).snapshotChanges().subscribe(data => {
    return data.map(e => {
      return {
        id: e.payload.doc.id,
        ...e.payload.doc.data()
      } as User;
    })
  });
```

**EDIT:**

Okay I think I tried to do it better, this is how I go throught the chats now:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/g205R.png

```
   db.collection('chats', ref => ref.where('groupId', '==', this.pathId).orderBy('date')).snapshotChanges().subscribe(data => {
  this.chatsList = data.map(e => {
    return {
      id: e.payload.doc.id,
      ...e.payload.doc.data()
    } as Chat;
  })
});
```

And this is the html with new change:

```
    <div class="card" *ngIf="authService.userData as user">

        <div id="card-box" class="card-box msg_head" ><!--  #scrollMe [scrollTop]="scrollMe.scrollHeight" DA ERROR  -->

            <div id="card-body" class="card-body msg_card_body">
              <div *ngFor="let chat of chatsList">
```

Still can't make it to get the userdata by userid from chat uid without infinite loop tho

EDIT2:
Okay I think I understand better how the asyncronous thing works and I was trying to build a frankenstein, Ill update this when I build it in another way.

EDIT3: 
Ok I fixed this by getting everything asyncronous (as it have to be) and doing a JOIN:

```
getPages(){ 
  const item: AngularFirestoreCollection = this.afs.collection(`pages`, (ref) => ref.orderBy('createdAt', 'desc'));
  return item.valueChanges().pipe( 
  switchMap(arr => { 
   const userObservable = arr.map(user => this._afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`) .valueChanges().pipe(first()) );
   return combineLatest(...userObservable) .pipe( map((...users) => { 
      arr.forEach((author, index) => { 
       author['author_avatar'] = users[0][index]['photoURL']; 
       author['author_username'] = users[0][index]['displayName']; 
      });
      return arr;
      })
      );
    })
    );
   }
```

Comment: If you need to get data once, why can't you use [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) instead of [`valueChanges()`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#valuechanges)?

Comment: it makes infinite loop just like valueChanges: this.userCollection.get()
.then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data().email);
        return doc.data().email;
    });
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
});

Comment: are you trying to get user by chat.id? is chatId stored in user.uid field?

Comment: Yeah I want to get the user by uid which I stored in chat (https://i.imgur.com/tGNDW2W.png)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to just make it work try any of your `getUser(id)` implementations, but instead of binding function it in the template - call it in ngOnInit, and bind the returned result instead.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getUser(someId);
}
....
*ngIf="userDT"
```

but really you have problems with understanding js asynchronious concepts and how to handle such situations and simple stackoverflow answer won't help to understand it better

Comment: because I need to call it with a different Id each time

Comment: call `this.getUser(someId)` when you need it, just remove this function call from the template and everything should go better that it is now

Comment: but I need to call it from the template because I get the id right there going throught the messages, im just trying to show the email of the user who wrote the message: https://i.imgur.com/GRupLAp.png

Comment: i ll post another answer of what you need to modify

Answer (score 0):

modify your method to return promise/observable of an item and not to store on `this`.
like here

```
getUser(uid:string){
  return this.firestore
    .collection('users')
    .valueChanges({ idField: uid });
}
and in the template
*ngIf="getUser() | async as otherUser"
```

Comment: Thanks for help. It still makes infinite loop I added console.log to show: https://i.imgur.com/MkylBEa.png. This is the component ts: https://i.imgur.com/3ynWpjV.png and the component html: https://i.imgur.com/oRz7HuC.png i send u screenshots i think theyre better in comments here for you hopefull

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed this by getting everything asyncronous (as it have to be) and doing a JOIN

```
getPages(){ 
      const item: AngularFirestoreCollection = this.afs.collection(`pages`, (ref) => ref.orderBy('createdAt', 'desc'));
      return item.valueChanges().pipe( 
      switchMap(arr => { 
       const userObservable = arr.map(user => this._afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`) .valueChanges().pipe(first()) );
       return combineLatest(...userObservable) .pipe( map((...users) => { 
          arr.forEach((author, index) => { 
           author['author_avatar'] = users[0][index]['photoURL']; 
           author['author_username'] = users[0][index]['displayName']; 
          });
          return arr;
          })
          );
        })
        );
       }
```